# Masking to WPF date picker

Tags: wpf

I want to add masking to WPF date picker control. I saw that DatePickerTextBox can not be extended any further.

So, I decided a add a interactivity behavior to it. I used following code for this:

Masked date picker class:

```
public class MaskedDatePicker : DatePicker
{
}
```

and I created a attached behavior like below:

```
public class DatePickerTextBoxInputMaskBehavior : Behavior<DatePickerTextBox>
{
}
```

Now in templates I attached the behavior:

```
<DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}"
    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <cleanPoc:DatePickerTextBoxInputMaskBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DatePickerTextBox>
```

Now every time i open the calender from datepicker application freezes because text changed in DatePickerTextBoxInputMaskBehavior got fired recursively. 
Any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base control (DatePicker) does things with the DatePickerTextBox that you cannot really control by attaching a behavior to the DatePickerTextBox...

Get a reference to the MaskedDatePicker control itself and set the Text property of the DatePickerTextBox when the SelectedDate property of the control gets set to a new value. Have a look at the following example and let me know if you need any clarification.

Good luck!

```
    public class DatePickerTextBoxInputMaskBehavior : Behavior<DatePickerTextBox>
        {
            ...
containing the event data.
            private void AssociatedObjectLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.Provider = new MaskedTextProvider(this.InputMask, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                this.Provider.Set(this.AssociatedObject.Text);
                this.Provider.PromptChar = this.PromptChar;
                this.SetText(this.Provider.ToDisplayString());

                MaskedDatePicker dp = FindVisualParent<MaskedDatePicker>(this.AssociatedObject);
                var textProp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(MaskedDatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, typeof(MaskedDatePicker));
                if (textProp != null)
                {
                    textProp.AddValueChanged(dp, OnHandler);
                }
            }

            private static T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
            {
                var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

                if (parent == null) return null;

                var parentT = parent as T;
                return parentT ?? FindVisualParent<T>(parent);
            }

            private void OnHandler(object s, EventArgs args)
            {
                this.UpdateText();
            }


            private void UpdateText()
            {
                if (this.Provider.ToDisplayString().Equals(this.AssociatedObject.Text))
                {
                    return;
                }

                MaskedDatePicker dp = FindVisualParent<MaskedDatePicker>(this.AssociatedObject);
                if (dp != null && dp.SelectedDate.HasValue)
                    SetText(dp.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); //format date here...


            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Sets the text.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
            private void SetText(string text)
            {
                this.AssociatedObject.Text = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? string.Empty : string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, text.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat));
            }

        }
    }
```